# Exclude control from scrolling

Tags: wpf

I have a situation in which `ScrollViewer` is set in the base class (`Window`) and my user control is dynamicaly added as a content of the window. Now, I want one of the controls (`ToolBar`) in my user control  to be excluded from scrolling (to stay visible on top). I know there is a property `HandlesScrolling` on the `Control` class but it is internal. I have no way to put the toolbar outside the `ScrollViewer` because I don't have access to it.
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think to do that is to make your control size itself to the outer `ScrollViewer` and then have its own inner `ScrollViewer` to handle scrolling. There's some example code below but the key is binding the `Height` of your control to the `ActualHeight` of the outer `ScrollerViewer` like this: `Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ScrollViewer}}}"`

Outer Scrollviewer:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <ListBox:HandlesItsOwnScrolling />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Your Control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ListBox.HandlesItsOwnScrolling"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ScrollViewer}}}" >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Row="0">Toolbar</Button>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
            <Border Background="AliceBlue" Height="1000" />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: It looks like a good idea, but so far it doesn't work (cannot find source for binding) because my custom control is injected later. I will try to set the binding at the right moment in code behind.

Comment: I solved it by finding the parent ScrollViewer using VisualTreeHelper and disabling it (binding didn't work in my case). Anyway, you gave me the idea, and you deserve the bounty. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Vale. Glad you got it working. I'm going to read up on VisualTreeHelper...